How do you write directly to user memory from kernel mode in Linux?
I am trying to write directly from a kernel module into a process that it creates without a copy. Note that I cannot simply allocate the memory in kernel mode and map it to userland like you would normally do, I need the memory to eventually originate from the process itself (eventually from a call to the CUDA runtime).
Right now I have a proc file setup with a write callback which I use to send the buffer from userland:
char *buffer;
const size_t PAGE_SIZE = getpagesize();
posix_memalign(&buffer,PAGE_SIZE,PAGE_SIZE);
*buffer = 89;
    
FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/dt/alloc", "w");
fwrite(buffer, 1, 100, fp);

In the kernel module I map the page to kernel memory and modify the first byte as follows:
static ssize_t write_proc_alloc(struct file *file, const char __user *ubuf, size_t count, loff_t *data)
{
    struct page *pages[1];
    mmap_read_lock(current->mm);
    pin_user_pages((unsigned long)ubuf,1, FOLL_WRITE, pages);
    char *buf = kmap(pages[0]);

    *buf = 123;

    kunmap(pages[0]);
    set_page_dirty(pages[0]);
    unpin_user_pages(pages, 1);
    mmap_read_unlock(current->mm);
}

I have made sure to set the page to dirty after, and yet still it remains unchanged after fwrite returns. Why is my modification not visible, and how do I directly modify the provided buffer without having to resort to copy_to_user and the like?

At most, this would only modify the standard I/O stream's buffer (which might not even be page aligned), not the original buffer. But even low level write system calls are not supposed to modify the passed in memory.

@IanAbbott Ah ok interesting, I thought it was passing the pointer directly, maybe I can write the pointer then :) "Supposed to" is besides the point, I have little choice unfortunately, there is no direct kernel API for CUDA so I need to use a proxy interface in userspace.

Using write instead of fwrite would avoid any standard I/O buffering. I'm not sure why you are writing instead of reading (read) though. If you want more complicated interactions, you can implement an ioctl handler.

My actual goal is to keep it pinned for the duration of the program, I am just using it as a way to pass the pointer. I'll take a look at ioctl thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it, seems I missed the point: that it is the difference between fwrite and write. Thanks!

So just an update: I tried this with write instead and got the same results as before, it seems the pointer you get is never the pointer into userspace. Going to mark my answer as correct as it provides the workaround.

Thanks to Ian Abbott for leading me down the right path.
The solution was to use a level of indirection, since the pointer passed to the kernel function write_proc_alloc is not the same one the user provides. Instead you write a pointer, copy that by value using get_user(ptr,(uintptr_t*)ubuf) and then from there map the memory and write as before.
